# Javascript syntax []() and ()()

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm having trouble understanding these javascript syntaxes. In the block of code below, on the second line. The square bracket is quickly followed by a round bracket or parentheses which I suspected is used to get arguments. I do not understand how this two  is being chained to form an expression and what it means.

```
 export const recipeCount = createReducer(0, {
      [types.ADD_RECIPE](state, action){
        return state + 1;
      }
    });
```

Also on this line, the connect method takes in two arguments, `(state) => {return {}}` and `mapDispatchToProps` . Then it is quickly follwed by () with an argument. At first, i though it was some of object casting in java but that doesn't make sense.

```
export default connect((state) => {return {}}, mapDispatchToProps)(AppContainer);
```

The code executes fine and produces expected result. I just don't understand what is going on. Pls Help, would be glad to get answersre accompanied with links to pages i can read for better understanding. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what's going on with the first one. For the second one, `connect()` is a function that returns a function so the second `()` is to immediately call that returned function.

Comment: The first one is a dynamic object literal property that is also an object method.  I find this not readable at all.  I would re-write that one.

Comment: That make sense. Thank you.

Comment: @BadmusTaofeeq If it's clear for you, I'd suggest you close that question.

Comment: To make it totally clear, here's a [documentation on Computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names)

Comment: This is still hideous. I can't believe that would in any way pass a code review.

Comment: @Gothdo That is not a good dup. It covers the shorthand object method, but not the computed property key aspect, nor the `()()` question.

Comment: @torazaburo This question is too broad anyway.

Comment: @JaredSmith I'm sure this hideous code would pass code reviews where it was written. this `[types.ADD_RECIPE]` smells like a committee designed factories and type hierarchies with a lot of verbose abstractions in between...

Comment: @Gothdo respectfully disagree: there are several as yet uncommon sugars in play here so its not a dupe of questions about any specific one, but it can be answered decisively in a one paragraph answer so its not too broad. I'm not saying its a great question, but I've seen plenty worse ones that are also not technically dupes.

Comment: @DenysSéguret agreed: some UMLWeenie got their smudgy fingerprints all over this.

Comment: @JaredSmith A question should ask one question; otherwise it's too broad. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222735/310998 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/310998

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answers are in the comment to the question. Had to copy them out again, so i can mark the question as answered and close it.

"Not sure what's going on with the first one. For the second one, connect() is a function that returns a function so the second () is to immediately call that returned function." – Ouroborus

"The first one is a dynamic object literal property that is also an object method. I find this not readable at all. I would re-write that one. – Davin Tryon"

and also a link to [Computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) to make it clearer from – Denys Séguret

Thanks Guys.

Comment: Could I suggest that you re-write the comments into a consistent answer ..  it would add a lot of value

Comment: Doubtful that we need an answer at all, since the individual questions are all well answered in other questions.