# How a javascript object can have only property without predefined key

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have some "dumb" question, sorry, but I really don't understand how it works.

In this createReducer call we are passing the second argument - js object (as I understand).

But I didn't see any key... only function. How it can works?

```
  export const todos = createReducer([], {
      [ActionTypes.ADD_TODO](state, action) {
        let text = action.text.trim()
        return [ ...state, text ]
      }
    })


function createReducer(initialState, handlers) {
  return function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
    if (handlers.hasOwnProperty(action.type)) {
      return handlers[action.type](state, action)
    } else {
      return state
    }
  }
}
```

I expected to see some like:

```
    {
          [ActionTypes.ADD_TODO] : (state, action) => {
                let text = action.text.trim()
                return [ ...state, text ]
              }
        }
```

The same with this construction: it's a function where is the key? How it can be?

```
const dynamicRoutes = {
    component : AppComponent,
    childRoutes : [
        {
            path : "/",
            getComponent(location, cb) {
                System.import("../modules/landing-page/LandingPage.module")
                    .then(loadRoute(cb))
                    .catch(errorLoading);
            }
        }

    ]
};
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions#Description

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript syntax [\]() and ()()](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41399719/218196)

Comment: Thank you guys Now I understand that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a shorthand notation for methods. The key is the name of the function. So `[ActionTypes.ADD_TODO](state, action) {` is equivalent to `[ActionTypes.ADD_TODO]: function(state, action) {`

Answer (score 2):

These are valid [object initializer](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-initializer) syntaxes.
The second example is simple case of `MethodDefinition` ([link to spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-method-definitions))

The case `[ActionTypes.ADD_TODO](state, action)` is also a `MethodDefinition`, but method/property name is defined as a `ComputedPropertyName` which has the syntax `[ AssignmentExpression[In, ?Yield] ]`.
In case of `ComputedPropertyNames` it's possible to put a variable/object property between square brackets and the value will be used as property name in the newly created object.